# Wrapping a C++ object in extern "C"

Tags: c++, c, cross-platform

consider a simple example class:

```
class BankAccount {
public:
   BankAccount() { balance =0.0; };
  ~BankAccount() {};
   void deposit(double amount) {
      balance += amount;
   }
   private:
      double balance;
};
```

Now say I want to wrap this in extern "C" so that I can call it from many different programming languages such as C# and Java.
I tried the following which seemed to work:

```
// cbankAccount.h:
extern "C" unsigned long createBackAccount(); 
extern "C" void deposit(unsigned long bankAccount, double amount);
// cbankAccount.cpp
unsigned long createBackAccount() {
  BankAccount *b = new BankAccount();
  return (unsigned long) b;
}
void deposit(unsigned long bankAccount, double amount) {
  BankAccount *b = (BankAccount*) bankAccount;
  b->deposit(amount);
}
```

Is this portable?
Is the type unsigned "unsigned long" large enough for an object pointer?
Any other problems with this approach?

Thank in advance for any answers!

Comment: How are those other languages going to access `BankAccount` if they don't have the class definition?

Comment: @Etienne, through the pointer (cast as a long) and the C-functions. A C-api for a C++ library I guess.

Comment: don't forget `disposeBankAccount()`!

Answer (score 10):

Yeah. It's bad. Really bad. `unsigned long`- just no. Return a properly typed `BankAccount*`- the other languages will see it on the other end as a generic pointer (such as System.IntPtr) and there's no need to return an untyped pointer when the binary interface doesn't type pointers anyway.

```
extern "C" BankAccount* CreateBankAccount() {
    return new BankAccount;
}
extern "C" void deposit(BankAccount* account, double amount) {
    account->deposit(amount);
}
```

Comment: +1 If you did that you'd have to write a different header file for any C clients. Since any C++ clients are not going to use the flattened version of the interface, `void*` makes more sense. But maybe there won't be any C clients in which case your approach is better!

Comment: @David: `#ifndef __cplusplus typedef struct BankAccount BankAccount; #endif`

Comment: I'm actually work on the API interface to my app today and although it's written in Delphi, I use exactly the same strategy that you describe in your answer at the boundary of my library!

Answer (score 9):

That basically looks fine with one proviso.  Trying to use an integer type to hold a pointer is not a great idea—much better to use `void*` since that, by definition, is the width of a pointer.

---

Actually, I think @DeadMG's answer is a cleaner approach than this.

Answer (score 5):

Type-strong is even better than void *.

```
typedef struct BankAccountProxy *  BankAccountPtr;

BankAccountPtr createBackAccount() {
  BankAccount *b = new BankAccount();
  return (BankAccountPtr) b;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not portable, because `unsigned long` may be not long enough for a pointer. A not so rare platform where this happens is win64.

Better to use `ptrdiff_t` or `void*`.

Comment: The correct type from the stdlib is `intptr_t` not `ptrdiff_t`.

Answer (score 3):

It would probably be platform dependent whether long is large enough (probably not on x86-64) an alternative is to use something like [swig](http://www.swig.org/)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use void* instead of unsigned long.